# Error in zero_range() using fviz_dend with large dataset of 1000

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is basically 1000 pick-up locations and I am trying to cluster them using a hierarchical clustering method. Since the large data set, the resulting dendogram is unreadable therefore I am trying to zoom in to the lower clusters. I use fviz_dend to display my dendogram and the code is as follows.

```
fviz_dend(res.hc, xlim = c(0:2), ylim = c(0:0.02))
```

However, it resulted in an error as follows along with traceback()

```
Error in zero_range(range) : x must be length 1 or 2
> traceback()
19: stop("x must be length 1 or 2")
18: zero_range(range)
17: expand_range(limits, expand[1], expand[2])
16: expand_range4(continuous_range_coord, expand)
15: expand_limits_continuous_trans(limits, expand, coord_limits)
14: expand_limits_continuous(limits, expand, coord_limits_scale)
13: expand_limits_scale(scale, expansion, limits, coord_limits = coord_limits)
12: view_scales_from_scale(scale_x, self$limits$x, self$expand)
11: f(..., self = self)
10: self$coord$setup_panel_params(scale_x, scale_y, params = self$coord_params)
9: (function (scale_x, scale_y) 
   {
       self$coord$setup_panel_params(scale_x, scale_y, params = self$coord_params)
   })(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]])
8: mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
7: Map(setup_panel_params, scales_x, scales_y)
6: f(..., self = self)
5: layout$setup_panel_params()
4: ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
3: ggplot_build(x)
2: print.ggplot(x)
1: (function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue? Thank you!